# What is the difference between __cause__ and __context__?

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x

These are attributes for Python exceptions, but I am having trouble wrapping my head around them. Python's documentation seems rather quiet about this. I took a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=__cause__#the-raise-statement) but am rather confused. So, what is the difference between the two and how are they used?

EDIT: On that note, how are they related to `__traceback__`, if at all?

EDIT 3: I guess I just don't understand `__cause__`. I finally understand `__traceback__` and `__context__`. Why does `attribute_error.__cause__` not refer to `AttributeError()`?

```
try:
    raise NameError() from OSError
except NameError as name_error:
    print('name_error.__cause__: %s' % repr(name_error.__cause__))
    print('name_error.__context__: %s' % repr(name_error.__context__))
    print('name_error.__traceback__: %s' % repr(name_error.__traceback__))
    try:
        raise AttributeError()
    except AttributeError as attribute_error:
        print('attribute_error.__cause__: %s' % repr(attribute_error.__cause__))
        print('attribute_error.__context__: %s' % repr(attribute_error.__context__))
        print('attribute_error.__traceback__: %s' % repr(attribute_error.__traceback__))
        raise attribute_error from IndexError
```

This outputs

```
name_error.__cause__: OSError()
name_error.__context__: None
name_error.__traceback__: <traceback object at 0x000000000346CAC8>
attribute_error.__cause__: None
attribute_error.__context__: NameError()
attribute_error.__traceback__: <traceback object at 0x000000000346CA88>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\test\test.py", line 13, in <module>
    raise attribute_error from IndexError
  File "C:\test\test.py", line 8, in <module>
    raise AttributeError()
AttributeError
```

Comment: The doc is thin because these are more or less internal variables that most Pythononeers do not have to even know about. The reason to mention them at all is a) they are visible and b) people who catch one error and raise another may need to know.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`__cause__` is the cause of the exception - due to the given exception, the current exception was raised. This is a direct link - X threw this exception, therefore Y has to throw this exception.

`__context__` on the other hand means that the current exception was raised while trying to handle another exception, and defines the exception that was being handled at the time this one was raised. This is so that you don't lose the fact that the other exceptions happened (and hence were at this code to throw the exception) - the context. X threw this exception, while handling it, Y was also thrown.

`__traceback__` shows you the stack - the various levels of functions that have been followed to get to the current line of code. This allows you to pinpoint what caused the exception. It is likely to be used (potentially in tandem with `__context__`) to find what caused a given bug.

Comment: I *think* I'm starting to get it. Do you mind providing a brief code snippet demonstrating what each of these are at each location in the code?

Comment: Okay, so I "moved the goalposts back". Now, I'm just asking for a bit of clarification. Check out my latest edit.

Comment: Because `from` is what gives `__cause__` it's value. You are printing `__cause__` before anything is there, and your `raise` statement with the `from` part is the wrong way round.