# Python "raise from" usage

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax, exception

What's the difference between `raise` and `raise from` in Python?

```
try:
    raise ValueError
except Exception as e:
    raise IndexError
```

which yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 2, in <module>
    raise ValueError
ValueError

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise IndexError
IndexError
```

and

```
try:
    raise ValueError
except Exception as e:
    raise IndexError from e
```

which yields

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 2, in <module>
    raise ValueError
ValueError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tmp.py", line 4, in <module>
    raise IndexError from e
IndexError
```

Comment: Have you read [PEP-3134](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/)?

Comment: Now use `raise IndexError from None`, say.

Comment: Heh. `raise IndexError from False` raises a `TypeError`, not an `IndexError`. Made my day.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between \_\_cause\_\_ and \_\_context\_\_?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235932/what-is-the-difference-between-cause-and-context)

Comment: Not sure if this is the right place to mention it, but to anyone using Spyder:
This entire construct does not work there. It's been an issue for over 3 years now (https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2943), but they seem to think there is no need for chained exceptions.

Comment: A working link to [pep-3134](https://peps.python.org/pep-3134/)

Answer (score 490, accepted):

The difference is that when you use `from`, the *`__cause__` attribute* is set and the message states that the exception was *directly caused by*. If you omit the `from` then no `__cause__` is set, but the *`__context__` attribute* may be set as well, and the traceback then shows the context as *during handling something else happened*.

Setting the `__context__` happens if you used `raise` in an exception handler; if you used `raise` anywhere else no `__context__` is set either.

If a `__cause__` is set, a `__suppress_context__ = True` flag is also set on the exception; when `__suppress_context__` is set to `True`, the `__context__` is ignored when printing a traceback.

When raising from a exception handler where you *don't* want to show the context (don't want a *during handling another exception happened* message), then use `raise ... from None` to set `__suppress_context__` to `True`.

In other words, Python sets a *context* on exceptions so you can introspect where an exception was raised, letting you see if another exception was replaced by it. You can also add a *cause* to an exception, making the traceback explicit about the other exception (use different wording), and the context is ignored (but can still be introspected when debugging). Using `raise ... from None` lets you suppress the context being printed.

See the [`raise` statement documenation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement):

> The `from` clause is used for exception chaining: if given, the second *expression* must be another exception class or instance, which will then be attached to the raised exception as the `__cause__` attribute (which is writable). If the raised exception is not handled, both exceptions will be printed:
>
> ```
> >>> try:
> ...     print(1 / 0)
> ... except Exception as exc:
> ...     raise RuntimeError("Something bad happened") from exc
> ...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
> ZeroDivisionError: int division or modulo by zero
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
> RuntimeError: Something bad happened
> ```
>
> A similar mechanism works implicitly if an exception is raised inside an exception handler or a `finally` clause: the previous exception is then attached as the new exception’s `__context__` attribute:
>
> ```
> >>> try:
> ...     print(1 / 0)
> ... except:
> ...     raise RuntimeError("Something bad happened")
> ...
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
> ZeroDivisionError: int division or modulo by zero
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
> RuntimeError: Something bad happened
> ```

Also see the [Built-in Exceptions documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#built-in-exceptions) for details on the context and cause information attached to exceptions.

Comment: Is there any reason to explicitly chain the exceptions using `from` and `__cause__` in lieu of the implicit `__context__`?  Are there any cases where one would attach a different exception than the one caught by the `except`?

Comment: @darkfeline: Lets say your database API supports opening databases from various sources, including the web and disk. Your API will *always* raise a `DatabaseError` if opening the database fails. But if the failure is the result of a `IOError` because a file failed to open or a `HTTPError` because a URL failed to work then that is context you want to include explicitly, so the developer using the API can debug why this is. At that moment you use `raise DatabaseError from original_exception`.

Comment: @darkfeline: If that developer is wrapping the use of the database API in their own API and wanted to pass on that `IOError` or `HTTPError` on to *their* consumers, then they'd have to use `raise NewException from databaseexception.__cause__`, now using a different exception from the `DatabaseException` that they just caught.

Comment: `__suppress_context__ = True` in your answer should be just `__suppress_context__`, no? Because the later part suggests it's only set to `True` if `raise ... from None` is used.

Comment: @FichteFoll not sure what you mean; you can set it explicitly to `True`, but it is automatically set to `True` for you when you use any `raise ... from ...` (`None` or otherwise).

Comment: After reading again I understand now. I assumed that `__suppress_context__`  would only be set to true if it was raised `from None` but it the traceback is printed differently if `__cause__` is set. Otherwise both `__cause__` and `__context__` would be printed.

Comment: Is there any `from __future__` for the `raise .. from` construct in Python 2?

Comment: @dan3: no, there isn't. Exception chaining is purely a Python 3 feature.

Comment: So in short, use `raise from` whenever I want to keep the original exception object, correct?

Comment: @laike9m: you mean when you are handling exception `foo`, and want to raise a *new* exception `bar`? Then you can use `raise bar from foo` and have Python state that `foo` *directly caused `bar`*. If you *don't* use `from foo`, then Python will still print both, but state that *during handling `foo`, `bar` was raised*, Different message, intended to flag a possible bug in the error handling.

Comment: I mean the newly raised exception's `__cause__` attr is the original exception, which maybe useful for future error handling, while not using `raise from` throws the original exception object away.

Comment: @laike9m: no, not when you used `raise` from inside an exception handler. `__context__` is still set then.

Comment: So it only depends on what you need the printed message to be?

Comment: @laike9m: exactly. Both are meant to be debugging aids, not end-user UI of course.

Comment: If code has been written for Python 3 and you want to modify it to work both on Python 2 and 3, what's the best way of doing that? Should I replace `raise Error(...) from e` with `e2 = Error(...); e2.__cause__ = e; raise e2` (except on separate lines, of course.) That would be the same as before on Python 3, and work on Python 2.7, right? Otherwise I'd need to have separate files for Python 2 and 3 and be careful when importing to check the version...

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: yes, you'd have to create the instance, set the `__cause__` attribute manually, then raise the updated exception. This works in 2 and 3. However, in Python 3, you may end up with a circular reference if you then don't delete the `e2` variable (as the `__traceback__` attribute that `raise` sets will contain an indirect reference to the frame and thus to the `e2` name, etc.). The `six` project [creates a function that uses `try...finally`](https://bitbucket.org/gutworth/six/src/ca4580a5a648fc75abc568907e81abc80b05d58c/six.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#six.py-715:733).

Comment: @MartijnPieters - One of us have misread the code in the `six` project. Line 731 is an `else`, for if your Python version is below 3.2. Line 733 shows that it'll simply `raise value` and ignore the `from_value` argument.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - Maybe I should finally just move on from Python 2.7... the final library I needed that I was waiting on (Fabric) appears to have a well maintained port now available in Python 3. I'll only be 8 years late to the party, and I always made sure my code ran in both versions... now I can finally abandon 2.7?

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare: If you are writing polyglot code, then it'll be run on both 2.7 and on 3.x, so in the 3.x case you really want the `finally` part to run; you did just set `__cause__` after all.

Answer (score 20):

In 2005, [PEP 3134, Exception Chaining and Embedded Tracebacks](https://peps.python.org/pep-3134/) introduced exception chaining:

- *implicit chaining* with explicit `raise EXCEPTION` or implicit raise (`__context__` attribute);
- *explicit chaining* with explicit `raise EXCEPTION from CAUSE` (`__cause__` attribute).

> ### Motivation
>
> During the handling of one exception (exception A), it is possible that another exception (exception B) may occur. In today’s Python (version 2.4), if this happens, exception B is propagated outward and exception A is lost. In order to debug the problem, it is useful to know about both exceptions. The `__context__` attribute retains this information automatically.
>
> Sometimes it can be useful for an exception handler to intentionally re-raise an exception, either to provide extra information or to translate an exception to another type. The `__cause__` attribute provides an explicit way to record the direct cause of an exception.
>
> […]
>
> ### Implicit Exception Chaining
>
> Here is an example to illustrate the `__context__` attribute:
>
> ```py
> def compute(a, b):
>     try:
>         a/b
>     except Exception, exc:
>         log(exc)
>
> def log(exc):
>     file = open('logfile.txt')  # oops, forgot the 'w'
>     print >>file, exc
>     file.close()
> ```
>
> Calling `compute(0, 0)` causes a `ZeroDivisionError`. The `compute()` function catches this exception and calls `log(exc)`, but the `log()` function also raises an exception when it tries to write to a file that wasn’t opened for writing.
>
> In today’s Python, the caller of `compute()` gets thrown an `IOError`. The `ZeroDivisionError` is lost. With the proposed change, the instance of `IOError` has an additional `__context__` attribute that retains the `ZeroDivisionError`.
>
> […]
>
> ### Explicit Exception Chaining
>
> The `__cause__` attribute on exception objects is always initialized to `None`. It is set by a new form of the `raise` statement:
>
> ```py
> raise EXCEPTION from CAUSE
> ```
>
> which is equivalent to:
>
> ```py
> exc = EXCEPTION
> exc.__cause__ = CAUSE
> raise exc
> ```
>
> In the following example, a database provides implementations for a few different kinds of storage, with file storage as one kind. The database designer wants errors to propagate as `DatabaseError` objects so that the client doesn’t have to be aware of the storage-specific details, but doesn’t want to lose the underlying error information.
>
> ```py
> class DatabaseError(Exception):
>     pass
>
> class FileDatabase(Database):
>     def __init__(self, filename):
>         try:
>             self.file = open(filename)
>         except IOError, exc:
>             raise DatabaseError('failed to open') from exc
> ```
>
> If the call to `open()` raises an exception, the problem will be reported as a `DatabaseError`, with a `__cause__` attribute that reveals the `IOError` as the original cause.
>
> ### Enhanced Reporting
>
> The default exception handler will be modified to report chained exceptions. The chain of exceptions is traversed by following the `__cause__` and `__context__` attributes, with `__cause__` taking priority. In keeping with the chronological order of tracebacks, the most recently raised exception is displayed last; that is, the display begins with the description of the innermost exception and backs up the chain to the outermost exception. The tracebacks are formatted as usual, with one of the lines:
>
> > The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> or
>
> > During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> between tracebacks, depending whether they are linked by `__cause__` or `__context__` respectively. Here is a sketch of the procedure:
>
> ```py
> def print_chain(exc):
>     if exc.__cause__:
>         print_chain(exc.__cause__)
>         print '\nThe above exception was the direct cause...'
>     elif exc.__context__:
>         print_chain(exc.__context__)
>         print '\nDuring handling of the above exception, ...'
>     print_exc(exc)
> ```
>
> […]

In 2012, [PEP 415, Implement Context Suppression with Exception Attributes](https://peps.python.org/pep-0415/) introduced exception context suppression with explicit `raise EXCEPTION from None` (`__suppress_context__` attribute).

> ### Proposal
>
> A new attribute on `BaseException`, `__suppress_context__`, will be introduced. Whenever `__cause__` is set, `__suppress_context__` will be set to `True`. In particular, `raise exc from cause` syntax will set `exc.__suppress_context__` to `True`. Exception printing code will check for that attribute to determine whether context and cause will be printed. `__cause__` will return to its original purpose and values.
>
> There is precedence for `__suppress_context__` with the `print_line_and_file` exception attribute.
>
> To summarize, `raise exc from cause` will be equivalent to:
>
> ```py
> exc.__cause__ = cause
> raise exc
> ```
>
> where `exc.__cause__ = cause` implicitly sets `exc.__suppress_context__`.

So in PEP 415, the sketch of the procedure given in PEP 3134 for the default exception handler (its job is to report exceptions) becomes the following:

```py
def print_chain(exc):
    if exc.__cause__:
        print_chain(exc.__cause__)
        print '\nThe above exception was the direct cause...'
    elif exc.__context__ and not exc.__suppress_context__:
        print_chain(exc.__context__)
        print '\nDuring handling of the above exception, ...'
    print_exc(exc)
```

Answer (score 5):

**The shortest answer**. [PEP-3134](https://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/) says it all. `raise Exception from e` sets the `__cause__` filed of the new exception.

**A longer answer** from the same PEP:

- `__context__` field would be set implicitly to the original error inside `except:` block unless told not to with `__suppress_context__ = True`.
- `__cause__` is just like context but has to be set explicitly by using `from` syntax
- `traceback` will always chain when you call `raise` inside an `except` block. You can get rid of traceback by a) swallowing an exception `except: pass` or by messing with `sys.exc_info()` directly.

**The long answer**

```
import traceback 
import sys

class CustomError(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__("custom")

def print_exception(func):
    print(f"\n\n\nEXECURTING FUNCTION '{func.__name__}' \n")
    try:
        func()
    except Exception as e:
        "Here is result of our actions:"
        print(f"\tException type:    '{type(e)}'")
        print(f"\tException message: '{e}'")
        print(f"\tException context: '{e.__context__}'")
        print(f"\tContext type:      '{type(e.__context__)}'")
        print(f"\tException cause:   '{e.__cause__}'")
        print(f"\tCause type:         '{type(e.__cause__)}'")
        print("\nTRACEBACKSTART>>>")
        traceback.print_exc()
        print("<<<TRACEBACKEND")


def original_error_emitter():
    x = {}
    print(x.does_not_exist)

def vanilla_catch_swallow():
    """Nothing is expected to happen"""
    try:
        original_error_emitter()
    except Exception as e:
        pass

def vanilla_catch_reraise():
    """Nothing is expected to happen"""
    try:
        original_error_emitter()
    except Exception as e:
        raise e

def catch_replace():
    """Nothing is expected to happen"""
    try:
        original_error_emitter()
    except Exception as e:
        raise CustomError()

def catch_replace_with_from():
    """Nothing is expected to happen"""
    try:
        original_error_emitter()
    except Exception as e:
        raise CustomError() from e

def catch_reset_trace():
    saw_an_error = False
    try:
        original_error_emitter()
    except Exception as e:
        saw_an_error = True
    if saw_an_error:
        raise CustomError()

print("Note: This will print nothing")
print_exception(vanilla_catch_swallow)
print("Note: This will print AttributeError and 1 stack trace")
print_exception(vanilla_catch_reraise)
print("Note: This will print CustomError with no context but 2 stack traces")
print_exception(catch_replace)
print("Note: This will print CustomError with AttributeError context and 2 stack traces")
print_exception(catch_replace_with_from)
print("Note: This will brake traceback chain")
print_exception(catch_reset_trace)
```

Will result in the following output:

```
Note: This will print nothing
EXECURTING FUNCTION 'vanilla_catch_swallow' 




Note: This will print AttributeError and 1 stack trace
EXECURTING FUNCTION 'vanilla_catch_reraise' 

        Exception type:    '<class 'AttributeError'>'
        Exception message: ''dict' object has no attribute 'does_not_exist''
        Exception context: 'None'
        Context type:      '<class 'NoneType'>'
        Exception cause:   'None'
        Cause type:         '<class 'NoneType'>'

TRACEBACKSTART>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 11, in print_exception
    func()
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 41, in vanilla_catch_reraise
    raise e
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 39, in vanilla_catch_reraise
    original_error_emitter()
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 27, in original_error_emitter
    print(x.does_not_exist)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'does_not_exist'
<<<TRACEBACKEND



Note: This will print CustomError with no context but 2 stack traces
EXECURTING FUNCTION 'catch_replace' 

        Exception type:    '<class '__main__.CustomError'>'
        Exception message: 'custom'
        Exception context: ''dict' object has no attribute 'does_not_exist''
        Context type:      '<class 'AttributeError'>'
        Exception cause:   'None'
        Cause type:         '<class 'NoneType'>'

TRACEBACKSTART>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 46, in catch_replace
    original_error_emitter()
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 27, in original_error_emitter
    print(x.does_not_exist)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'does_not_exist'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 11, in print_exception
    func()
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 48, in catch_replace
    raise CustomError()
CustomError: custom
<<<TRACEBACKEND



Note: This will print CustomError with AttributeError context and 2 stack traces
EXECURTING FUNCTION 'catch_replace_with_from' 

        Exception type:    '<class '__main__.CustomError'>'
        Exception message: 'custom'
        Exception context: ''dict' object has no attribute 'does_not_exist''
        Context type:      '<class 'AttributeError'>'
        Exception cause:   ''dict' object has no attribute 'does_not_exist''
        Cause type:         '<class 'AttributeError'>'

TRACEBACKSTART>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 53, in catch_replace_with_from
    original_error_emitter()
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 27, in original_error_emitter
    print(x.does_not_exist)
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'does_not_exist'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 11, in print_exception
    func()
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 55, in catch_replace_with_from
    raise CustomError() from e
CustomError: custom
<<<TRACEBACKEND



Note: This will brake traceback chain
EXECURTING FUNCTION 'catch_reset_trace' 

        Exception type:    '<class '__main__.CustomError'>'
        Exception message: 'custom'
        Exception context: 'None'
        Context type:      '<class 'NoneType'>'
        Exception cause:   'None'
        Cause type:         '<class 'NoneType'>'

TRACEBACKSTART>>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 11, in print_exception
    func()
  File "/Users/eugene.selivonchyk/repo/experiments/exceptions.py", line 64, in catch_reset_trace
    raise CustomError()
CustomError: custom
<<<TRACEBACKEND
```