# What is the best way to raise request errors?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm reading some source code which raises errors for bad requests in the following way:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("www.google.com")   # This won't work because it's missing the http://
if response.ok is False or response.json()['status'] != 'success':
    raise Exception("API error: {}".format(response.json()['message']))
```

I was thinking that the last two lines could be replaced with

```
response.raise_for_status()
```

I actually don't see any difference in the error returned. In both cases it is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kurt/Documents/Scratch/requests_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    response = requests.get("www.google.com")   # This won't work because it's missing the http://
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 451, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 382, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 304, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/home/kurt/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 362, in prepare_url
    to_native_string(url, 'utf8')))
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL 'www.google.com': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://www.google.com?
```

It seems to me that `raise_for_status()` is more succinct and perhaps also doesn't lose information on the original exception (cf. [Use of "except Exception" vs. "except ... raise" in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40280776/use-of-except-exception-vs-except-raise-in-python)). Would this indeed be a better approach?

Comment: You never reached the `if` statement, so no, there is no difference. You can't test a response when the request is never sent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`response.raise_for_status()` only raises an exception if the response status code is not a 200 response. The second case, where `response.json()['status'] != 'success'` is true, is *not* covered.

You have a **different** error, however. You never get to the `if` test, because the exception is raised by the `requests.get()` call. You failed to pass in a schema (no `http://` or `https://` at the start). Because the exception is raised in the `requests.get()` expression, the next line is simply never executed. No request is even sent, so you can't make any assertions about the response either.

The test has more problems:

- `requests.ok is False` is not idiomatic Python; you'd use `not requests.ok` instead
- If `requests.ok is False` is true, then the `requests.json()` call will most likely fail altogether, so the next line using `response.json()['message'])` will produce a different exception.

Comment: I indeed forgot the sanity check of running the `get` without any of the ensuing lines. But indeed, according to http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/?highlight=success, the `success` attribute checks whether the response could be JSON decoded, which is not the same as the status code being 200.