# Catching 2 exceptions and using "as" not working as expected

Tags: python, exception, raise

I'm trying to catch two exceptions as follows:

```
class TestException:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = [1, 2, 3]

def main():
    test_exception = TestException()
    try:
        test_exception.y[1] = 4.0
    except (IndexError, AttributeError) as e:
        raise e('Why does this not work?')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

but I get the following error:

**TypeError: 'AttributeError' object is not callable**

Why does this occur? Because the following works fines:

```
raise AttributeError('This does work!')
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `e` is the *instance*, not the class. Either use `type(e)` to get the class, or look at `raise from` (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/24752395/3001761).

Answer (score 0):

Following on from @jonrsharpe, the following works fine:

```
raise type(e)('This works now.')
```

or

```
raise Exception('This works now.') from e
```