# Consider explicitly re-raising using the 'from' keyword pylint suggestion

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, pylint, raise

I have a small python code in which I am using exception handling.

```
def handler(event):
    try:
        client = boto3.client('dynamodb')
        response = client.scan(TableName=os.environ["datapipeline_table"])
        return response
    except Exception as error:
        logging.exception("GetPipelinesError: %s",json.dumps(error))
        raise GetPipelinesError(json.dumps({"httpStatus": 400, "message": "Unable to fetch Pipelines"}))

class GetPipelinesError(Exception):
    pass
```

pylint warning gives me " Consider explicitly re-raising using the 'from' keyword ".
I saw few other posts, where they used from and raised an error. I made modifications like this

```
except Exception as GetPipelinesError:
    logging.exception("GetPipelinesError: %s",json.dumps(GetPipelinesError))
    raise json.dumps({"httpStatus": 400, "message": "Unable to fetch Pipelines"}) from GetPipelinesError
```

Is this the right way to do ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pylint raise-missing-from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63738900/pylint-raise-missing-from)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No. The purpose of `raise`-`from` is to [chain exceptions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exception_chaining). The correct [syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) in your case is:

```py
except Exception as error:
   raise GetPipelinesError(json.dumps(
       {"httpStatus": 400, "message": "Unable to fetch Pipelines"})) from error
```

The expressions that follow `raise` and `from` must be exception classes or instances.