# Repacking or wrapping of imported error or exception types in python3 modules

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I have this module `A` that might raise an exception from an imported module `B`. Can I "wrap" or "repack" the exception so that I can handle the exception in the importing script without having to import `B`?

`A.py`:

```py
import B

def do_something(parameters):
    try:
        B.function(**parameters)
    except B.some_exception as eee:
        raise wrapper(eee)
```

`script.py`

```py
import A

try:
    do_something("glorious parameter")
except B.wrapped_exception:
    handling()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just import the exception from B like

`from B import some_exception`

or add a general exception catch with some other logic, like a matching message, to check if it the specific exception like

```
try:
    do_something("glorious parameter")
except Exception as e:
    if str(e) == "Matching message":
        handling()
    else:
        raise e
```

However, bare exceptions are usually not recommended because they indiscriminately catch everything ([What is wrong with using a bare 'except'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54948548/what-is-wrong-with-using-a-bare-except)) so I would go with your original solution or the first suggestion.

**Edit:**

I re-read your issue and I think I got what you meant. You can chain exceptions with the keyword `from` and raise some general error like `ValueError` such as:

```
def do_something(parameters):
    try:
        B.function(**parameters)
    except B.some_exception as eee:
        raise ValueError("Wrapped exception") from eee
```

and then catch the `ValueError` as usual.

See: [Python "raise from" usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752395/python-raise-from-usage)

Comment: Thanks, you are right, my code example was not reflecting the real code. Catching bare exceptions is an absolute no-no (and will bite you in the fanny someday)
But importing the Exception from the module B is what I want to prevent

Comment: @Hoffmann I see what you mean, check the edit.