# Try until no exception, leaving behind the remaining tries

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

So I am trying to deal with an encoding/decoding error that I get sometimes. Usually it is fixed by encoding in mbcs, but I wanted to also give other situations to try for the same exception. However, I only want it to keep trying in error handling until it hits a situation without an exception.

My problem is that whether I try to use functions, multiple blocks ending with except: pass, or nested try/excepts, it always runs correctly but still gives me my final error message anyways: "'Unable to Encode most likely due to special characters.'". Can anyone help me understand how I can make the error handling stop and not continue on if there is no exception? I realize there might be better ways to do this anyways, but for a learning perspective, why am I still getting the final message and how can it be avoided if my code ran with no exception.

```
InputPath = ''
    OutputPath = ''
    
    def ConvertButtonPress():
        try:
            if InputPath == '' or OutputPath == '':
                RunButton['state'] = "disabled"
            else:
                RunButton['state'] = "normal"   
            with open(InputPath) as CSVInput:
                with open(OutputPath, 'w', newline='') as TXTOutput:
                    reader = csv.DictReader(CSVInput, delimiter=',')
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(TXTOutput, reader.fieldnames, delimiter='|')
                    writer.writeheader()
                    writer.writerows(reader)
        except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
            ConvertButtonPress_mbcs()
    def ConvertButtonPress_mbcs():
        try:
            if InputPath == '' or OutputPath == '':
                RunButton['state'] = "disabled"
            else:
                RunButton['state'] = "normal"   
            with open(InputPath, encoding="mbcs") as CSVInput:
                with open(OutputPath, 'w', newline='') as TXTOutput:
                    reader = csv.DictReader(CSVInput, delimiter=',')
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(TXTOutput, reader.fieldnames, delimiter='|')
                    writer.writeheader()
                    writer.writerows(reader)
        except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
            ConvertButtonPress_utf8()
    def ConvertButtonPress_utf8():
        try:
            if InputPath == '' or OutputPath == '':
                RunButton['state'] = "disabled"
            else:
                RunButton['state'] = "normal"   
            with open(InputPath, encoding="utf-8") as CSVInput:
                with open(OutputPath, 'w', newline='') as TXTOutput:
                    reader = csv.DictReader(CSVInput, delimiter=',')
                    writer = csv.DictWriter(TXTOutput, reader.fieldnames, delimiter='|')
                    writer.writeheader()
                    writer.writerows(reader)
        except (UnicodeEncodeError, UnicodeDecodeError):
            RunButton['text'] = 'Unable to Encode most likely due to special characters.'
```

Comment: You should at least log whatever exception causes the next function in the chain to be called to get some clue as to *why* the text of the `RunButton` is ultimately changed. That said, this should be heavily refactored, as only a small fraction of the code actually needs to be repeated in the event of an error.

Comment: what @chepner said, but if you did need to chain exceptions (which I don't think is the best idea here), there is a way to do that. Look into raise ... from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24752395/python-raise-from-usage