# Is there a way to test `raise X from Y` using pytest?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I would like to know if there is a better way and what the options are for testing `raise X from Y` using pytest.

Here's a dummy example:

```py
import pytest

class AException(Exception):
    pass

class A:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        raise AException("Class A")

class C:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        try:
            A()
        except AException as err:
            raise ValueError("C Failed") from err

def test_class_c():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError):
        C()
```

In this example, the test should confirm that it raised `ValueError` from `AException` from `Class A`.

The obvious solution is to pass the message like this:

```py
except AException as err:
    raise ValueError(f"C Failed: {err}") from err
```

and then match it:

```py
def test_class_c():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError, match="Class A"):
        C()
```

but is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't come across an official way of doing this but one way could be to check `__cause__` (or `__context__`) of the most "recent" exception:

```
def test_class_c():
    with pytest.raises(ValueError) as exc_info:
        C()
    assert isinstance(exc_info.value.__cause__, AException)
    assert exc_info.value.__cause__.args == ("Class A",)
```

PEP regarding `__cause__` and `__context__`: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/

[What is the difference between __cause__ and __context__?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235932/what-is-the-difference-between-cause-and-context)

Comment: Nice suggestion, thanks!